# Receive Notification on new data entry in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I want to receive notifications in my flutter mobile App when a new Product or item is added. Currently I am receiving data through JSON API response in my APP. How did i receive the Firebase Notifications or updates?  And which parameters does firebase require to generate the notifications.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) for listening to changes in your database (if you're using something like Firestore or Realtime Database), and in that listener use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) to send notifications to devices.